# RLE algorithm applied to bmp file

Tags: c, bitmap

I am currently facing issues when trying to apply the run-length algorithm to a .bmp picture. When I am doing the encoding, all is working well, but at decoding there is a problem and I cannot figure it out, namely I cannot read the number of repetitive pixels and thus my output is a blank image. When I use the debugger, the number of repetitive pixels is not readed correctly from the binary file (the result of applying RLE on the bitmap file). Here is my code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//structure defiens bitmap header
struct BITMAPFILEHEADER{
   uint8_t type[2];//type of file (bit map)
   uint32_t size;//size of file
   uint16_t reserved1;//
   uint16_t reserved2;//
   uint32_t offsetbits;//off set bits
} __attribute__ ((packed));

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER{
   uint32_t size;//bitmap size
  // uint16_t w2;
   uint32_t width;//width of bitmap
  //uint16_t h2;
   uint32_t height;//hight of bitmap

   uint16_t planes;
   uint16_t bitcount;
   uint32_t compression;// compression ratio (zero for no compression)
   uint32_t sizeimage;//size of image
   long xpelspermeter;
   long ypelspermeter;
   uint32_t colorsused;
   uint32_t colorsimportant;
} __attribute__ ((packed));


 //const char* INPUT_FILE = "/home/bogdan/bee.bmp";
const char* INPUT_FILE = "/home/bogdan/Linux.bmp";
const char* ENCODED_FILE = "/home/bogdan/encoded.bin";
const char* DECODED_FILE = "/home/bogdan/decoded.bmp";

typedef struct SINGLE_PIXEL{
    uint8_t green;//Green level 0-255
    uint8_t red;  //Red level 0-255
} PIXEL;

int comparePixels(PIXEL, PIXEL);
void encode();
void decode(char*);

int main()
{
    encode();
    decode(ENCODED_FILE);
    return 0;
}

void encode() {
    uint32_t i=0;//to count pixels read
    uint32_t pixno=0;//number of pixels to read

    struct BITMAPFILEHEADER source_head;//to store file header
    struct BITMAPINFOHEADER source_info;//to store bitmap info header
    PIXEL pixel;// the current pixel

    FILE *in;// bitmap imput pointer file
    FILE *out;//output file pointer

    if(!(in=fopen(INPUT_FILE,"rb")))//open in binary read mode
    {
    printf("\ncan not open file");//error at opening file
    exit(-1);
    }


out=fopen(ENCODED_FILE,"wb");//opne in binary write mode
//read the headers to source file
fread(&source_head,sizeof(struct BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,in);
fread(&source_info,sizeof(struct BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,in);

//write the headers to the output file
fwrite(&source_head,sizeof(struct BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,out);
fwrite(&source_info,sizeof(struct BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,out);

//cumpute the number of pixels to read
pixno=source_info.width*source_info.height;

// init list of pixels
PIXEL pixArr[pixno];
printf("total pixels: %d", pixno);

//printf("w:%f h:%u pn:%lu", (source_head.size/1024.0/1024), source_info.height, pixno);
uint32_t sum = 0;
//read, modify and write pixels
for(i=0;i<pixno;++i)
{
    //read pixel form source file
    fread(&pixel,sizeof(PIXEL),1,in);
    pixArr[i] = pixel;
}
for (i = 0; i < pixno; i++) {
   // printf ("i = %d\tred = %d green = %d blue = %d\n",i, pixArr[i].red, pixArr[i].green, pixArr[i].blue);
    int runlength = 1;
    while ((i + 1) < pixno) {
        if (comparePixels(pixArr[i], pixArr[i+1]) == 0){
        // printf ("i = %d\t red = %d green = %d blue = %d\n",i, pixArr[i].red, pixArr[i].green, pixArr[i].blue);
            runlength++;
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    //fprintf(out, "%d", runlength);
    fwrite(&runlength, sizeof(runlength), 1, out);
    fwrite(&pixel,sizeof(PIXEL),1,out);
    sum += runlength;
    runlength = 0;
}
    //write the modification to the output file
    //close all fiels
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    printf("sum = %d",sum);
}

void decode(char * filePath) {
    uint32_t i=0;//to count pixels read
    uint32_t j=0;
    uint32_t totalPixels=0;//number of pixels to read
    uint32_t pixelRepetition = 1;
    struct BITMAPFILEHEADER source_head;//to store file header
    struct BITMAPINFOHEADER source_info;//to store bitmap info header
    PIXEL pixel;// the current pixel

    FILE *in;// bitmap encoded pointer file
    FILE *out;//decoded bitmap file pointer
    if (!(in = fopen(filePath, "rb"))) {
        printf("\ncan not open file");
        exit(-1);
    }
    out = fopen(DECODED_FILE, "wb");
    //read the headers to source file
   fread(&source_head,sizeof(struct BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,in);
   fread(&source_info,sizeof(struct BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,in);

   //write the headers to the output file
   fwrite(&source_head,sizeof(struct BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,out);
   fwrite(&source_info,sizeof(struct BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,out);

   totalPixels=source_info.width*source_info.height;

   while(i < totalPixels) {

        fread(&pixelRepetition, sizeof(pixelRepetition), 1, out);
        fread(&pixel,sizeof(PIXEL),1,in);

       for (j = 0; j < pixelRepetition; j++) {
            fwrite(&pixel,sizeof(PIXEL),1,out);
       }
       i += pixelRepetition;
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}

int comparePixels(PIXEL px1, PIXEL px2) {
    if (px1.red == px2.red && px1.green == px2.green && px1.blue == px2.blue) {
      return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

My implementation is working as follow: I read the header of a bmp file and put it directly to another file. After that I compare pixels to see if they have the same RGB values. If this is true  (according to comparePixels function) I put the number of consecutive identical pixels and one pixel (the one which is repeated) into the file. This is the encode phase. At decoding, I am reading the header of the image and then I am trying to read the number of repetitions (1 default, means no repetitive pixels) and the pixel which is repeated. I will really appreciate any type of help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Also, "there is a problem" is not a helpful description.  You should describe *exactly* what output you see, and how it compares to what you expected.

Comment: Trust me, the reason that I have posted here the code is that I didn't manage to spot the error using the debugger. You have not been paying attention to my description, I said :"My first thought is that I am not correctly reading an int from a binary file". If you know something that could help me, and if you want to, please say it if you want, otherwise let's avoid these discussion.

Comment: That's not how SO works, I'm afraid; it's not a crowd-sourced debugger. I'm encouraging you to improve your question, so that it will get better help faster, rather than being closed.  Also, note that "my first thought..." is not a description of the behaviour/symptoms of your program.

Comment: Try a small hand-constructed sample where you know what you expect the reading code to do. Watch it in the debugger and see where it does something you didn't expect. (Or "play computer", working through the code line by line and variable by variable on paper.) Figure out why, fix it, move on to the next bug. This being C, triple-check ever use of pointer or array references to make sure they're within bounds.

Comment: You incorrectly conclude that encoding works (all is well? - no it's not).  There are problems with your encode routine.  Because it doesn't crash doesn't mean it doesn't work right.  You should do a hex dump of the output and compare it with what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeatedly writing *out* only the very last pixel you read *in*:

```
fwrite(&runlength, sizeof(runlength), 1, out);
fwrite(&pixel,sizeof(PIXEL),1,out);
```

You need to write out your *current* pixel instead:

```
fwrite(pixArr[i], sizeof(PIXEL),1,out);
```

Comment: A hex dump of the output should have shown up the error right away.

Comment: @Matt: agreed. The OP thought the *repetition* value got read wrong, but the code suggests that should not have been not the problem.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for your nice answers!! I have found that, indeed, my encode routine was wrong and I have corrected it. Now I have another question, how can I read an int from a binary file? Because I didn't made it using something like `fscanf(in, "%d", &pixelRepetition);` Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Costy: ..?? You used `fread (&pixelRepetition ..` here, and that *is* a relatively good way to "read an int from a binary file". (There are a few other good ways; `fscanf` is not.) Post a new question if in doubt.

Comment: And beware of endianess if you're wanting portable code and portable file format.

Comment: @Matt: hency my qualifier "relatively". I suppose "portable" only comes after "working at all". Still, it's something I always try to keep in mind when working on this low level.